# Having problems with a search method between Arrays and Array lists

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist

OK so I'm trying to design a simple program that checks to see if a substring of length 4 characters is within all initial strings.  Here is my code as follows:

```
public class StringSearch{
private String[] s1Array = {"A","C","T","G","A","C","G","C","A","G"};
private String[] s2Array = {"T","C","A","C","A","A","C","G","G","G"};
private String[] s3Array = {"G","A","G","T","C","C","A","G","T","T"};
//{for (int i = 0; i < s1Array.length; i++){
//    System.out.print(s1Array[i]);
//}}//check if Array loaded correctly
/**
 * This is the search method.
 * 
 * @param  length   length of sub string to search
 * @param  count    counter for search engine
 * @param  i        for-loop counter
 * @return subStr   returns strings of length = 4 that are found in all 3 input strings with at most 
 *                  one mismatched position.
 */
public String Search()
{
    int length = 4;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<StringSearch> subStr = new ArrayList<StringSearch>();
    //String[] subStr = new String[4];
    do
    {
    for (i = count; i < length; i++){
        subStr.add(s1Array[i]); // cant find .add method???
        count = count + 1;
    }
    if (s2Array.contains(subStr) && s3Array.contains(subStr)){ //can't find .contains method???
        System.out.println(subStr + "is in all 3 lists.");
    }
    if (count = s1Array.length){
        System.out.println("Task complete.");
    }
    else{
        count = count - length;
        count = count + 1;
    }
    }while (count <= s1Array.length);
}
```

}

For some reason, Java cannot seem to find the .add or .contains methods and I have no idea why.  So my approach was to turn the initial Strings each into an array (since the assignment specified each string would be exactly N elements long, in this case N = 10) where 1 letter would be 1 element.  The next thing I did was set up a for loop that would scan s1Array and add the first 4 elements to an ArrayList subStr which is used to search s2Array and s3Array.  Here is where .add isn't a valid method, for whatever reason.  Commenting that out and compiling again, I also ran into an issue with the .contains method not being a valid method.  Why won't this work?  What am I missing?  Logically, it seems to make sense but I guess maybe I'm missing something in the syntax?  Help would be appreciated, as I'm a Java novice.

Comment: `Arrays` and `Arraylists` are completely different datatypes in Java.

Comment: .add and .contains are part of the ArrayList class. subStr.add(s1Array[i]); wont work because subStr is define as a <StringSearch> and s1Array is defined as a String

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html for more information about ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of errors and misunderstandings here.

Let's start with **#1**

```
private String[] s1Array = {"A","C","T","G","A","C","G","C","A","G"};
```

Making an array of strings is just silly, you should either use a single string or an array of characters.

```
private String s1 = "ACTGACGCAG";
```

Or

```
private char[] s1Array = {'A','C','T','G','A','C','G','C','A','G'};
```

Now **#2**

```
ArrayList<StringSearch> subStr = new ArrayList<StringSearch>();
```

This means you are trying to make an ArrayList  that contains objects of type StringSearch. StringSearch is a class that contains your three arrays and your Search function so I don't think this is what you want.

If you wanted to make a list of 3 strings you might do something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add(s1);
stringList.add(s2);
stringList.add(s3);
```

Now say you defined s1, s2 and s3 as strings you can do something like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= s1.length() - 4; i++)
{
    String subStr = s1.substring(i, i + 4);
    if(s2.contains(subStr) && s3.contains(subStr))
    {
        System.out.println(subStr + " is in all 3 lists.");
    }
}
System.out.println("Task Complete.");
```

The above code should achieve what it looks like you are trying to do. However, it should be noted that this isn't the most efficient way, just a way, of doing it. You should start with some more basic concepts judging by the code you have so far.

Comment: I really like this approach!  Thank you for taking the time to break it down.  I didn't specify all that I was trying to do with this particular project, but what I wanted to do with what I'd gotten so far.  The end product will be able to check each of the strings with a substring of 4 characters to see if subString can be found within all 3 original strings and matches at least 3/4 letters.  For instance, if we start with 'ACTG' as subString then 'AATG', 'ACAG', 'TCTG' would be valid examples of what I'm searching for.  It was for this reason that I used Arrays/Lists, to examine each letter.

Comment: This approach will still work. Just use s1.charAt(index); to compare individual letters.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish that just using strings, or am I on the right track in breaking it down into Arrays and Lists?  As I'm sure you can tell, I'm a complete Java novice.  The syntax of this language is somewhat confusing to me. My brain knows what it wants the program to do, but I'm having a hard time putting that into terms that Java will understand.

Comment: Ah OK, I will give it a try.  Thank you

Comment: Sure, if you feel I've answered your question satisfactorily please accept the answer. :)

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < s1.length() - 4; i++) - can you explain s1.length() - 4?  Is that accomplishing what I was trying to do with the counter under else where it would subtract length?

Comment: We don't want to move past the last index of the string s1 when getting the substring, because we  add 4 to the argument in substring we need to subtract 4 from the terminating case of the loop.

Comment: Although I changed the conditional in my edit to <= s1.length() so that the last substring isn't missed.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring subStr as ArrayList you can call add or contains only with StringSearch objects as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
ArrayList<StringSearch> subStr = new ArrayList<StringSearch>();
```

Replace it with:

```
String subStr = "";
```

And within the for loop to get the first 4 letters in s1 to be in its own string (subStr) add the line:

```
subStr += s1Array[i];
```

Also, s1Array is a String array, and not a String. The .contains method is a method that belongs to String variables, so for eg. the way you have it implemented, you can say s1Array[i].contains. But you cannot say s1Array.contains. If you change your String arrays to Strings and edit your code to suit, everything should work the way you expect it to work.

Comment: No problem :). Also, if you're not finding the function you're looking for (eg .contains()) then you should check the String API to see how to use it.. always check the API lol.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to educate yourself on the concept of Java generics.
The most basic thing about generics is that once you declare a collection, here it is the arraylist, as  you can only add objects of StringSearch.
Second of all, logically what you can do is to implement an algorithm called 
[Longest Common Subsequence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) Check in pairs whether the longest subsequeces are 4 or not on the arrays.